# how to search for the actual number not absolute

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a program that will find a number value from a range in vba and returns the address of the cell, but the program searches for the number in its absolute form not in actual value. When I search the range for 0.5 for example, and in the range there is -0.5 it will give the location of -0.5 if it comes first. Is there any way for the program to search for the actual not the absolute number? This is the program:

```
Function findvalue(minvalue As Range, indicated As Range, reference As Range) As Variant

For n = 0 To indicated.Rows.Count - 1

Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(indicated.Row + n, indicated.Column).Find(minvalue.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

 If Not c Is Nothing Then
    findvalue = c.Address
    findvaluerow = c.Row
    findvaluecolumn = c.Column

   GoTo finish
End If
Next
For n = 0 To reference.Rows.Count - 1
Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(reference.Row+n, reference.Column).Find(minvalue.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
     findvalue = c.Address
     findvaluerow = c.Row
     findvaluecolumn = c.Column
       GoTo finish
 End If
Next
findvalue = 0
finish:
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, first of all, do not use Goto. Just google it, I don't want to write down the reasons for the one millionth time. But goto is very bad practice.

As for your actual question, try adding the `LookAt:=xlWhole` parameter to your .Find function. That way it will only find cells where the whole search value is matched.

```
Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(indicated.Row + n, Indicated.Column).Find(minvalue.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

To avoid goto, write it like this:

```
For n = 0 To indicated.Rows.Count - 1
   Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(indicated.Row + n, indicated.Column).Find(minvalue.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Next
if c is nothing then
  For n = 0 To reference.Rows.Count - 1
     Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(reference.Row+n, reference.Column).Find(minvalue.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  Next
End If

If Not c Is Nothing Then
   findvalue = c.Address
   findvaluerow = c.Row
   findvaluecolumn = c.Column
Else
   findvalue = 0
End If
```

Cleaner, brighter, easier to read and follow. Does the same, but also works. :)